# Presenting second view controller without loosing navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, navigation, wkwebview

I have written the following code that presents a second view controller whenever the user clicks on a link of a webpage. However whenever I present it the second view controller hides the navigation bar.

I would like to be able to dismiss the newly presented view by allowing the user to click "back" in the navigation bar. How can I do this?

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction!,
decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)!){
/* Do not allow links to be tapped */

if navigationAction.navigationType == .LinkActivated{
decisionHandler(.Cancel)

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("helloview") as UIViewController

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

return
}
decisionHandler(.Allow)
}
```

---

This is the way it looks. I click on the link and then the second view is presented. The view is a simple UIViewController with just a label on it. However I have **lost the navigation bar**..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to 'push' the view controller, with something like:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should push the new view controller onto the navigation stack, instead of presenting it as a modal view controller. Replace

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I would accept both. Cobra's one had the most correct syntax, yours was the most informative. Upvote to both, thanks.